# ¿Por qué usamos subjuntivo con "parece"?

Tags: subjuntivo

Estoy estudiando español. He hecho muchos ejercicios con el subjuntivo. Quiero preguntar: ¿por qué esta oración *"A mis padres les parece increible que yo (poder) pueda tocar la guitarra"* está correcta? Creo que podemos usar el modo indicativo, porque es un facto. Además, la palabra "parece" es una que típicamente se usa con el modo indicativo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La razón por la que se usa subjuntivo en la oración:

- A mis padres les parece increíble que yo **pueda** tocar la guitarra.

NO es la presencia de "parece" sino la presencia de "increíble". De hecho, si "increíble" no estuviera, se usaría indicativo:

- A mis padres les parece que yo **puedo** tocar la guitarra.

A diferencia de algunos pocos adjetivos que indican certeza (ej. "obvio"), "increíble", al igual que tantos otros adjetivos calificativos, indica un juicio de valor, y esto es lo que induce el uso del subjuntivo.

Answer (score 1):

La razón por la que se utiliza el subjuntivo con la palabra "**parece**" en esta oración es porque se está expresando una opinión o percepción, y no un hecho concreto. **El subjuntivo se utiliza para expresar acciones hipotéticas, posibles, dudosas o no confirmadas.**

En el ejemplo que has dado, "*A mis padres les parece increíble que yo (poder) pueda tocar la guitarra*", se está expresando la percepción o la opinión de los padres de que les resulta increíble que su hijo pueda tocar la guitarra. No se está afirmando que el hecho sea cierto o no, sino que se está expresando una percepción subjetiva.

Es por eso que se utiliza el subjuntivo en la parte de la oración que expresa la acción de tocar la guitarra, ya que se está expresando una posibilidad o una hipótesis en lugar de un hecho concreto. **La forma correcta sería** "*A mis padres les parece increíble que yo pueda tocar la guitarra*", con el verbo "**poder**" en modo subjuntivo.

Así pues, **el subjuntivo** se utiliza con la palabra "**parece**" ya que se está expresando una percepción o una opinión subjetiva en lugar de un hecho concreto, y por tanto, se utiliza para expresar una posibilidad o una hipótesis.

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta: concordancia.

En primer lugar, deberías disociar la cláusula principal ('...les parece increíble') de la subordinada ('que yo pueda...'). Hay muchas frases similares en donde ésta última concuerda sólo estando en subjuntivo.

Ampliando la respuesta de @Gustavson: en una frase como 'Les parece que yo *puedo* tocar la guitarra' el verbo de la subordinada (poder) concuerda estando en indicativo—en este caso el estilo usado en la cláusula principal es muy 'directo' y por ende trae connotaciones de certeza. Pero cualquier cambio que hagamos en la oración que; o bien le dé un matiz a duda; o bien directamente transforme el hecho en irreal, improbable o imposible; nos llevará irremediablemente a tener que conjugar el verbo subordinado en subjuntivo para no 'desafinar'. En tu ejemplo, tus padres simplemente no terminan de tomar el hecho por cierto y así necesitamos que el verbo *pueda* esté en subjuntivo para que acompañe con la idea que expresa la oración. Otros ejemplos para completar el argumento:

- *No* les parece que yo *pueda* tocar la guitarra.
- ¿Les parece que yo *puedo/podría/pueda* tocar la guitarra?
- Me gusta cuando *tocás* la guitarra.
- Me gustaría que *toqués/tocaras* la guitarra.

Creo que en las últimas dos queda aún más claro el punto al que quería llegar, porque en ambos casos la preferencia del hablante es un hecho dado. Pero el verbo de la subordinada en un caso da a entender que el oyente ha tocado la guitarra y en el otro no necesariamente es así.

Por último—y esto ya es más personal—dudo mucho que sea posible enunciar una especie de 'ley universal' que indique cuándo debe ser usado el subjuntivo y cuándo el indicativo en subordinadas. Cada quien tendrá sus argumentos sobre por qué es correcto cierto uso para una frase dada, yo he presentado el mío. Lo que sí te puedo sugerir es que pensar en la concordancia del verbo con la frase es algo que casi nunca falla—al menos para los nativos. Sino, buscar algo como 'usos principales del subjuntivo' y memorizarse una lista de las situaciones más frecuentes es algo que también puede ser muy acertado, y más eficiente que una disquisición para intentar convencerse sobre 'por qué está bien que un tal uso de un tal verbo en una tal frase sea así'.