# No hay nadie que yo conozca

Tags: gramática

¿Por qué es "nadie que yo conozca" en vez de "nadie que yo conozco"?

> "Señorías, hoy día ya somos capaces de fabricar un coche con cero emisiones, pero no hay nadie que yo conozca personalmente que pueda permitirse un coche así, y no imagino que nadie de este Parlamento pueda hacerlo." ([fuente](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/CRE-6-2006-07-04_ES.html?redirect))

Answer (score 2):

Se debe a los criterios establecidos para la concordancia del subjuntivo en cláusulas subordinadas. Cuando las mismas son introducidas a partir de una negación, se requiere que el verbo acompañe a la sensación de duda/imposibilidad que se desea transmitir en el mensaje. El subjuntivo cumple perfectamente esta función. En tu ejemplo esto se ve en dos situaciones:

> (...) **no** hay **nadie** que yo **conozca**

> (...) **no** imagino que **nadie** de este Parlamento **pueda** hacerlo

Si, en cambio, se quisiera expresar una afirmación:

> (...) hay **alguien** que yo **conozco**

> (...) **alguien** de este Parlamento **puede** hacerlo

Pero al agregar **imagino** debemos considerar dos posibles situaciones:

> (...) **imagino** que (tal vez) alguien de este Parlamento **podría** hacerlo

> (...) **imagino** que alguien de este Parlamento **puede** hacerlo

En el primer caso, aún el estado de duda no se ha abandonado por completo, por lo que el condicional es lo que mejor concuerda. En el segundo caso, el hablante literalmente está imaginando algo con certeza absoluta—algo que no tiene mucho sentido decirlo.

En las preguntas por lo general también se usa el subjuntivo para expresar duda. Si se usa el indicativo, las mismas tienen un tono confirmatorio:

> ¿Hay alguien que yo conozca que **pueda** permitirse un coche así?

> Hay alguien que conocemos que **puede** permitirse un coche así, ¿**cierto**?

Como ves, las situaciones a considerar son muchas. No hace mucho apareció [una pregunta similar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/41977/por-qu%C3%A9-usamos-subjuntivo-con-parece) sobre casos en donde el verbo debe ir en subjuntivo para concordar y ya dije que dudo que pueda enunciarse una máxima que sirva definitivamente para todas las situaciones posibles en las que esto ocurre. De todas formas, espero que te haya servido la respuesta.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Una persona puede sentirse segura de que una cosa es imposible, entonces yo no sabía que imposibilidad siempre se trata como duda. Creo que entiendo ahora: "que X sea imposible" es duda de X, no de su imposibilidad.

Comment: Claro, eso también es una buena forma de pensarlo

Answer (score 0):

En la frase "**nadie que yo conozca personalmente**", se utiliza el subjuntivo ("*conozca*") en lugar del indicativo ("*conozco*") porque se está hablando de una situación hipotética o potencial que podría no ser verdadera. El hablante no está seguro de si existe alguien que pueda permitirse un coche con cero emisiones o no.

El subjuntivo se utiliza para expresar una acción o situación hipotética, posible pero no necesariamente real. En este caso, el hablante está expresando una opinión o suposición sobre algo que no está seguro de que sea verdad, por lo que se utiliza el subjuntivo para indicar la incertidumbre.

Así pues, la frase "**nadie que yo conozca personalmente**" utiliza el subjuntivo en tercera persona del singular ("*conozca*"), en lugar del indicativo ("*conozco*"), en este contexto, para expresar una incertidumbre hipotética.

Comment: Hola, Diego y tac: ¡Muchísimas gracias por las detalladas explicaciones de Ustedes!

Comment: ¡ Gracias a ti Maurice !